# What are the scoping or visibility constraints in Java?

Tags: java, c++, scope

I have started programming in Java since 2000, while in C++ since 1987. So, most of the times I could grasp Java concepts fairly easily aptly aided by C++ knowledge. On certain occasions, though, it gives me a "cultural" shock(for a person ingrained with C++ culture). If I have the following program in C++:

```
// override.cpp
class Base
{
public:
   void f(int) { }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   void f(char *) { }
};

int main()
{
   Derived d;
   d.f(5); // This line throws a compilation error
}
```

invoking f(5) through a Derived object d throws an error, as within the scope of Derived class, f() can accept only a character pointer. If I translate this program into Java:

```
// Override.java
class Base
{
    public void f(int i) { System.out.println("Base.f()"); }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    public void f(String s) { System.out.println("derived.f()"); }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        d.f(5);
    }
}
```

The compiler does not throw any error and the program produces the output:

```
Base.f()
```

which's obviously misleading. Am I not supposed to get a compilation error for calling a function that's not available within Derived's scope?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html - in short: the function _is_ available (and there is little you can do against it).

Comment: There's nothing obvious about this being misleading. My experience with both languages (I also learned C++ first) is that for most programmers, the Java behavior is the intuitive one and the C++ behavior is confusing.

Comment: How is it misleading? `f(int i)` is inherited, and so when you pass an `int` to `f`, that variant gets executed.

Comment: having `Derived` extending `Base` you can call all the inherited methods from `Base` by a reference of `Derived`. Which part do you think is misleading?

Comment: You **can't** translate this C++ program into Java. Java does not have pointers. It would be more interesting if you posted two programs that *were* equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ it does not search base class to call a function/method by default. You need to explicitly specify for the same by the keyword `using` like `using Base::f;` in your case. But in case of Java, it does by default.The using statement brings the overload function into the same scope so that it can participate in overload resolution. Below C++ code works fine for me. So the difference is only in default behavior.

```
class Base
{
public:
   void f(int) { }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
using Base::f; // this line allow you to use function from base class
   void f(char *) { }
};

int main()
{
   Derived d;
   d.f(5); // This line throws a compilation error
}
```

Comment: 'In C++ it does not search base class to call a function/method by default' is nonsense.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit why it is nonsense

Answer (score 1):

The overriding method must have same argument list.
If not then functions work as overloaded functions.
In above case your base class function is matched on `d.f(5);` call.

Answer (score 0):

In java, non-private members such as `public void f(int i)` will be inherited by subclass, which means it will be a method member of subclass, so both

- `public void f(String s)`
- `public void f(int i)`

is accessible in subclass.

Answer (score 0):

All public functions are available from the class and all of its base classes (all the way up to `Object.class`). The key here is the declared type of the instance. For example:

```
Base b = new Derived();
b.f(10); // prints Base.f()
b.f("foo"); // does not compile

Derived d = new Derived();
d.f(10); // prints Base.f()
d.f("foo"); // prints derived.f()
```

Even though b's runtime type is `Derived.class`, the declared type is `Base.class`. You see the same behavior with interfaces:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

You only get access to methods declared in `List` and not all of `ArrayList`.